# laravel gulpfile elixr .publish()

Tags: php, laravel, gulp, laravel-elixir

i am following the laracasts tutorial,

Over there they had no error during tutorial,
But when i am trying to run gulp command i get error

```
c:\xampp\htdocs\projects\ims>gulp
c:\xampp\htdocs\projects\ims\gulpfile.js:16
        .publish(
         ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at c:\xampp\htdocs\projects\ims\gulpfile.js:16:10
    at Elixir (c:\xampp\htdocs\projects\ims\node_modules\laravel-elixir\index.js:3:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (c:\xampp\htdocs\projects\ims\gulpfile.js:14:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Liftoff.handleArguments (C:\Users\sizzling\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.js:116:3)
```

Here is my gulp file

```
elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.less('app.less')
        .publish(
        'jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
        'public/js/vendor/jquery.js'
    )
        .publish(
        'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js',
        'public/js/vendor/bootstrap.js'
    )
        .publish(
        'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css',
        'public/css/vendor/font-awesome.css'
    )
        .publish(
        'font-awesome/fonts',
        'public/css/fonts'
    );
});
```

i know i must have done someway wrong but can't find out where did i go wrong?
Any Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `.publish()` function was an alias to `.copy()` with the bower path already set, however its since been removed so you need to use `.copy()`. Something such as this should work

```
.copy(
    mix.bowerDir + '/path/to/lib/lib.js',
    'public/js/lib.js'
);
```

https://github.com/laravel/elixir/commit/b6d59b9f68978224064964a75a7639f95aa2eeee